# Knockout validation beyond message display

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am working on KnockOut validation and so far so good. I do have a question though. I have some code like the following:

```
 shippingMethodModel.Description.extend({ required: true });
```

And that shows a validation message below BUT does it set a flag or something which I can read to disable my save button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same need recently, so I'll try to translate what I did based on the line of code you provided above...

Try adding a ko.computed observable similar to the following:

```
shippingMethodModel.formIsNotValid = ko.computed(function () {
    // original line
    // var errors = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.validation.group(self));

    // ** oops, not "self" in this case

    // UPDATED line
    var errors = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.validation.group(shippingMethodModel));
    return (errors.length > 0);
});
```

**UPDATE**
I made a correction in the code above after noticing my error.

For those declaring such a model/class as a function all at once, this code may look similar to the following:

```
var ShippingMethodModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.shippingMethodId = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
    self.description = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

    self.formIsNotValid = ko.computed(function () {
        var errors = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.validation.group(self));
        return (errors.length > 0);
    });
};
```

**/UPDATE**

**UPDATE2**
Based on input from @ericb in the comments below, I made a change to the way I'm implementing my own solution, which I'll demonstrate by adapting the example code in my update above:

```
var ShippingMethodModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.shippingMethodId = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
    self.description = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

    self.formIsNotValid = ko.observable(false);

    self.validateObservableFormField = function (nameOfObservableToValidate, 
                                                 data, event) {
        for (var prop in data) {
            if (prop === nameOfObservableToValidate) {
                var theObservable = data[prop];
                theObservable.valueHasMutated();
                ko.validation.validateObservable(theObservable);
                if (theObservable.error) {
                    self.formIsNotValid(true);
                }
                else {
                    if (self.formIsNotValid()) {
                        var errors = 
                            ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.validation.group(self));
                        self.formIsNotValid(errors.length > 0);
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    };        
};
```

Notice that I've now defined `formIsNotValid` as an observable, but I'm using the `validateObservableFormField` function to help me with pre-submit form validity determination.  This change ensures that the `ko.validation.group` function is called only as needed, and that call should only be needed when the observable being validated is valid, but `formIsNotValid` is true (to handle the case where that current observable was the one that had set `formIsNotValid` to true).

Here's an example of how I'm doing this:

```
<input data-bind="value: description, 
                  event: { blur: function(data, event) {
                                     validateObservableFormField('facilityName', 
                                                                  data, 
                                                                  event) 
                                 }
                         }" />
```

*goofy formatting to eliminate horizontal scroll*

**NOTE:** I was already using this technique, but I've adapted it to improve the performance of checking whether or not the form is valid. **@Californicated**, I realized after my last comment that calling this function from the blur event of validated form fields is why I was seeing my save/submit button toggle between enabled and disabled states.

Thanks again to @ericb for the performance tip.

Further tips, from anyone, are always welcome!

**/UPDATE2**

Once you've got that in place, disabling the button is a matter of binding to that `formIsNotValid` computed observable in whatever way makes sense for how you intend to disable the button, e.g. `css: { 'ui-state-disabled': formIsNotValid }` and/or `disable: formIsNotValid` and/or some other method(s).

Hope this helps, and let me know if you run into trouble.

Comment: Hi, i am sorry for the misjudgment. I can see that code is computed when the page loads. I am using enable:formIsNotValid  but after first page load, if there is an error, it does not seem to disable it.

Comment: @Californicated hmmm... did you bind to `enable` as you have written above, or to `disable`?  `formIsNotValid` works for me when bound  `disable` on the button.  Also, I must emphasize that the `formIsNotValid` function should be a member of the class/model that owns the observables being validated.  See the update I provided in my answer above for additional guidance, and let me know if you have any questions.  Cheers!

Comment: You really don't want to call `group` inside of a computed like that. It can be a rather expensive call depending upon the complexity of the model, and it also will re-evaluate itself on its own. Try calling it outside of the computed, and then just have the computed return the `isValid` observable.

Comment: Excellent and detailed explanations Jimmym. That was really helpful:).

Answer (score 2):

I would setup the following:

```
saveEnabled = ko.computed(function(){
    // possible other logic
    return shippingMethodModel.Description.isValid();
});
```

and then in your HTML:

```
<button data-bind="enable: saveEnabled"> Save </button>
```

Or, if you have multiple properties on your model, you could do something like:

```
ko.validation.group(shippingMethodModel);
```

and then in your HTML:

```
<button data-bind="enable: isValid"> Save </button>
```

the `group` function adds an `isValid` property to whatever it groups.

Comment: Hi I tried your solution and it works too. But I will have to set up the solution for each field if I want to work on more fields than just the description. Jimmy's solution is one time code, it does not require revisit. Oterwise both solutions are just great :).

Comment: See edits - Your question really doesn't say whether you are trying validate a model with multiple properties or a single property.